# Automatic Tailwind Class Sorting with Prettier doesn't work as described in documentation

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, tailwind-css, prettier

I'm encountering an issue with the Automatic Tailwind Class Sorting plugin for Prettier on macOS and VSCode. According to the [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/blog/automatic-class-sorting-with-prettier), custom classes should be sorted to the front of the class list. However, in my case, these custom classes are being treated as normal classes and are not being sorted correctly.

For example, Prettier should format the following HTML code:

```
<p class="shadow-card left-4 mt-2 text-[11px] text-gray-text">
```

But it's actually formatting it like this:

```
<p class="left-4 mt-2 text-[11px] text-gray-text shadow-card">
```

Interestingly, my colleagues who are using Windows and Linux report that the plugin works correctly for them. We are all using the same version of Prettier and the Automatic Tailwind Class Sorting plugin. I've compared our configuration files and they seem to be the same.

Steps I've Taken:

- Checked that Prettier and the plugin are up to date.
- Compared configuration files with colleagues and found no
  differences.
- Tested the plugin on my colleagues' systems, and it worked as
  expected.

It's causing significant problems when it comes to comparing code changes in Git. Unnecessary reordering of classes is being detected as changes, leading to confusion and noise in our version control history.

Despite trying these steps, the issue persists. I'm at a loss for what might be causing this behavior.

Logs form debug console:

```
"INFO" - 12:25:52] Formatting file:///Users/kamilwojtowicz/Desktop/work/offerboard/packages/frontend/src/routes/%28appLayout%29/account/profile/%2Bpage.svelte
["INFO" - 12:25:52] Using config file at '/Users/kamilwojtowicz/Desktop/work/offerboard/packages/frontend/.prettierrc'
["INFO" - 12:25:52] PrettierInstance:
{
  "modulePath": "/Users/kamilwojtowicz/Desktop/work/offerboard/node_modules/prettier/index.js",
  "version": "2.8.8",
  "prettierModule": {
    "doc": {
      "builders": {
        "line": {
          "type": "line"
        },
        "softline": {
          "type": "line",
          "soft": true
        },
        "hardline": {
          "type": "concat",
          "parts": [
            {
              "type": "line",
              "hard": true
            },
            {
              "type": "break-parent"
            }
          ]
        },
        "literalline": {
          "type": "concat",
          "parts": [
            {
              "type": "line",
              "hard": true,
              "literal": true
            },
            {
              "type": "break-parent"
            }
          ]
        },
        "lineSuffixBoundary": {
          "type": "line-suffix-boundary"
        },
        "cursor": {
          "type": "cursor"
        },
        "breakParent": {
          "type": "break-parent"
        },
        "trim": {
          "type": "trim"
        },
        "hardlineWithoutBreakParent": {
          "type": "line",
          "hard": true
        },
        "literallineWithoutBreakParent": {
          "type": "line",
          "hard": true,
          "literal": true
        }
      },
      "printer": {},
      "utils": {},
      "debug": {}
    },
    "version": "2.8.8",
    "util": {},
    "__internal": {
      "errors": {},
      "coreOptions": {
        "CATEGORY_CONFIG": "Config",
        "CATEGORY_EDITOR": "Editor",
        "CATEGORY_FORMAT": "Format",
        "CATEGORY_OTHER": "Other",
        "CATEGORY_OUTPUT": "Output",
        "CATEGORY_GLOBAL": "Global",
        "CATEGORY_SPECIAL": "Special",
        "options": {
          "cursorOffset": {
            "since": "1.4.0",
            "category": "Special",
            "type": "int",
            "default": -1,
            "range": {
              "start": -1,
              "end": null,
              "step": 1
            },
            "description": "Print (to stderr) where a cursor at the given position would move to after formatting.\nThis option cannot be used with --range-start and --range-end.",
            "cliCategory": "Editor"
          },
          "endOfLine": {
            "since": "1.15.0",
            "category": "Global",
            "type": "choice",
            "default": [
              {
                "since": "1.15.0",
                "value": "auto"
              },
              {
                "since": "2.0.0",
                "value": "lf"
              }
            ],
            "description": "Which end of line characters to apply.",
            "choices": [
              {
                "value": "lf",
                "description": "Line Feed only (\\n), common on Linux and macOS as well as inside git repos"
              },
              {
                "value": "crlf",
                "description": "Carriage Return + Line Feed characters (\\r\\n), common on Windows"
              },
              {
                "value": "cr",
                "description": "Carriage Return character only (\\r), used very rarely"
              },
              {
                "value": "auto",
                "description": "Maintain existing\n(mixed values within one file are normalised by looking at what's used after the first line)"
              }
            ]
          },
          "filepath": {
            "since": "1.4.0",
            "category": "Special",
            "type": "path",
            "description": "Specify the input filepath. This will be used to do parser inference.",
            "cliName": "stdin-filepath",
            "cliCategory": "Other",
            "cliDescription": "Path to the file to pretend that stdin comes from."
          },
          "insertPragma": {
            "since": "1.8.0",
            "category": "Special",
            "type": "boolean",
            "default": false,
            "description": "Insert @format pragma into file's first docblock comment.",
            "cliCategory": "Other"
          },
          "parser": {
            "since": "0.0.10",
            "category": "Global",
            "type": "choice",
            "default": [
              {
                "since": "0.0.10",
                "value": "babylon"
              },
              {
                "since": "1.13.0"
              }
            ],
            "description": "Which parser to use.",
            "choices": [
              {
                "value": "flow",
                "description": "Flow"
              },
              {
                "value": "babel",
                "since": "1.16.0",
                "description": "JavaScript"
              },
              {
                "value": "babel-flow",
                "since": "1.16.0",
                "description": "Flow"
              },
              {
                "value": "babel-ts",
                "since": "2.0.0",
                "description": "TypeScript"
              },
              {
                "value": "typescript",
                "since": "1.4.0",
                "description": "TypeScript"
              },
              {
                "value": "acorn",
                "since": "2.6.0",
                "description": "JavaScript"
              },
              {
                "value": "espree",
                "since": "2.2.0",
                "description": "JavaScript"
              },
              {
                "value": "meriyah",
                "since": "2.2.0",
                "description": "JavaScript"
              },
              {
                "value": "css",
                "since": "1.7.1",
                "description": "CSS"
              },
              {
                "value": "less",
                "since": "1.7.1",
                "description": "Less"
              },
              {
                "value": "scss",
                "since": "1.7.1",
                "description": "SCSS"
              },
              {
                "value": "json",
                "since": "1.5.0",
                "description": "JSON"
              },
              {
                "value": "json5",
                "since": "1.13.0",
                "description": "JSON5"
              },
              {
                "value": "json-stringify",
                "since": "1.13.0",
                "description": "JSON.stringify"
              },
              {
                "value": "graphql",
                "since": "1.5.0",
                "description": "GraphQL"
              },
              {
                "value": "markdown",
                "since": "1.8.0",
                "description": "Markdown"
              },
              {
                "value": "mdx",
                "since": "1.15.0",
                "description": "MDX"
              },
              {
                "value": "vue",
                "since": "1.10.0",
                "description": "Vue"
              },
              {
                "value": "yaml",
                "since": "1.14.0",
                "description": "YAML"
              },
              {
                "value": "glimmer",
                "since": "2.3.0",
                "description": "Ember / Handlebars"
              },
              {
                "value": "html",
                "since": "1.15.0",
                "description": "HTML"
              },
              {
                "value": "angular",
                "since": "1.15.0",
                "description": "Angular"
              },
              {
                "value": "lwc",
                "since": "1.17.0",
                "description": "Lightning Web Components"
              }
            ]
          },
          "plugins": {
            "since": "1.10.0",
            "type": "path",
            "array": true,
            "default": [
              {
                "value": []
              }
            ],
            "category": "Global",
            "description": "Add a plugin. Multiple plugins can be passed as separate `--plugin`s.",
            "cliName": "plugin",
            "cliCategory": "Config"
          },
          "pluginSearchDirs": {
            "since": "1.13.0",
            "type": "path",
            "array": true,
            "default": [
              {
                "value": []
              }
            ],
            "category": "Global",
            "description": "Custom directory that contains prettier plugins in node_modules subdirectory.\nOverrides default behavior when plugins are searched relatively to the location of Prettier.\nMultiple values are accepted.",
            "cliName": "plugin-search-dir",
            "cliCategory": "Config"
          },
          "printWidth": {
            "since": "0.0.0",
            "category": "Global",
            "type": "int",
            "default": 80,
            "description": "The line length where Prettier will try wrap.",
            "range": {
              "start": 0,
              "end": null,
              "step": 1
            }
          },
          "rangeEnd": {
            "since": "1.4.0",
            "category": "Special",
            "type": "int",
            "default": null,
            "range": {
              "start": 0,
              "end": null,
              "step": 1
            },
            "description": "Format code ending at a given character offset (exclusive).\nThe range will extend forwards to the end of the selected statement.\nThis option cannot be used with --cursor-offset.",
            "cliCategory": "Editor"
          },
          "rangeStart": {
            "since": "1.4.0",
            "category": "Special",
            "type": "int",
            "default": 0,
            "range": {
              "start": 0,
              "end": null,
              "step": 1
            },
            "description": "Format code starting at a given character offset.\nThe range will extend backwards to the start of the first line containing the selected statement.\nThis option cannot be used with --cursor-offset.",
            "cliCategory": "Editor"
          },
          "requirePragma": {
            "since": "1.7.0",
            "category": "Special",
            "type": "boolean",
            "default": false,
            "description": "Require either '@prettier' or '@format' to be present in the file's first docblock comment\nin order for it to be formatted.",
            "cliCategory": "Other"
          },
          "tabWidth": {
            "type": "int",
            "category": "Global",
            "default": 2,
            "description": "Number of spaces per indentation level.",
            "range": {
              "start": 0,
              "end": null,
              "step": 1
            }
          },
          "useTabs": {
            "since": "1.0.0",
            "category": "Global",
            "type": "boolean",
            "default": false,
            "description": "Indent with tabs instead of spaces."
          },
          "embeddedLanguageFormatting": {
            "since": "2.1.0",
            "category": "Global",
            "type": "choice",
            "default": [
              {
                "since": "2.1.0",
                "value": "auto"
              }
            ],
            "description": "Control how Prettier formats quoted code embedded in the file.",
            "choices": [
              {
                "value": "auto",
                "description": "Format embedded code if Prettier can automatically identify it."
              },
              {
                "value": "off",
                "description": "Never automatically format embedded code."
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "optionsModule": {
        "hiddenDefaults": {
          "astFormat": "estree",
          "printer": {},
          "locStart": null,
          "locEnd": null
        }
      },
      "optionsNormalizer": {},
      "utils": {}
    },
    "__debug": {}
  }
}
["INFO" - 12:25:52] Using ignore file (if present) at /Users/kamilwojtowicz/Desktop/work/offerboard/.prettierignore
["INFO" - 12:25:52] File Info:
{
  "ignored": false,
  "inferredParser": "svelte"
}
["INFO" - 12:25:52] Detected local configuration (i.e. .prettierrc or .editorconfig), VS Code configuration will not be used
["INFO" - 12:25:52] Prettier Options:
{
  "filepath": "/Users/kamilwojtowicz/Desktop/work/offerboard/packages/frontend/src/routes/(appLayout)/account/profile/+page.svelte",
  "parser": "svelte",
  "useTabs": true,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "trailingComma": "none",
  "printWidth": 100,
  "plugins": [
    "/Users/kamilwojtowicz/Desktop/work/offerboard/node_modules/prettier-plugin-svelte/plugin.js",
    "/Users/kamilwojtowicz/Desktop/work/offerboard/node_modules/prettier-plugin-tailwindcss/dist/index.js"
  ],
  "pluginSearchDirs": [
    "/Users/kamilwojtowicz/Desktop/work/offerboard/packages/frontend"
  ],
  "endOfLine": "auto"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note! The `prettier-plugin-tailwindcss` plugin should be on the end of the plugin list in your `.prettier` config. Example:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "prettier-plugin-organize-attributes",
    "prettier-plugin-organize-imports",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss"// Move to the end of the list
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue but got things working again by adding  plugins: ["prettier-plugin-tailwindcss"] to my .prettierrc file.

Example .prettierrc.cjs:

```
// prettier.config.js, .prettierrc.js, prettier.config.cjs, or .prettierrc.cjs

/** @type {import("prettier").Config} */
const config = {
  bracketSameLine: true,
  plugins: ["prettier-plugin-tailwindcss"],
};

module.exports = config;
```

Looks like a lot of people have been running into this issue: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/prettier-plugin-tailwindcss/issues/176#issuecomment-1657636771

Answer (score 0):

I installed `"prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "0.4.1",` instead of `"prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.5.10",`. Restarted VS Code and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by @Samer worked for me. Here are the steps I took
First I uninstalled prettier-plugin-tailwindcss by running

```bash
npm uninstall prettier-plugin-tailwindcss
```

then I installed the specific version

```bash
npm install prettier-plugin-tailwindcss@0.4.1 -D
```

The `-D` flag will install the plugin as a dev dependency.